# Reading files in xamarin forms as a src folder

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to read a `file.txt` from a `src` folder inside my project. But when I write `File.ReadAllText("PATH")` I don't know the path for the file. The file is also inside a views folder.

`string text = File.ReadAllText();`

This is my project folder:

[image: Project folder]

I'm trying to read from popuppage.xaml to src/.txt file

Comment: Check out this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows#loading-files-embedded-as-resources

Comment: Another option is to put the content of the file into a `string` variable (if it is not too big).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Fullpath of embedded resource Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66261607/get-fullpath-of-embedded-resource-xamarin-forms)

Comment: is the `build action` of the file set to `content`?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms code runs on multiple platforms - each of which has its own filesystem. Previously, this meant that reading and writing files was most easily performed using the native file APIs on each platform. Alternatively, embedded resources are a simpler solution to distribute data files with an app.
You can check this document to learn more about File Handing in Xamarin Forms https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows